# Where is the root A-D-N (Alef-Dalet-Nun) used as a verb?

Tags: hebrew

Where can one read where the verb A-D-N (Alef-Dalet-Nun) is used?

(My understanding is that Hebrew nouns come from Hebrew verbs. I am just curious to read the verb uses of the root word of "ADoN". If one can not find it in the TaNaKH, then other sources, such as Talmudic Hebrew would do. Regardless whether Hebrew nouns come from Hebrew verbs or not, I am still interested in the answer to my question.)

Comment: Why do you think that _all_ nouns come from verbs? ?בית? לילה

Comment: "Where can one read where the verb A-D-N (Alef-Dalet-Nun) is used?" This is my only question and statement. Any other else, such as the question you asked, is quite literally parenthetical which opens up a different topic.

Comment: For being sure, I checked a concordance, and there is no such usage.

Comment: You might be referring to useage in the TaNaKH, which I anticipated in my post. Therefore I suggested the next step would be Talmudic Hebrew (or are you saying you consulted a Talmudic concordance?)

Answer (score 8):

1. According to the Even-Shushan dictionary, there are no verbs based on that root.
2. אדן in Hebrew means base, pillar, like in ["אדני המשכן"](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9F) - pillars of the tabernacle (Shemot 38:31 thanx mbloch).
3. The word אדון has no connection to the root אדן and comes *presumably* from לדון (to judge, to master) where א is a prefix.

Comment: Your point number 3 sounds very likely to be true, and I had conjectured that myself. Do you have a source for it? Does Even-Shushan write that?

Comment: If you're familiar with Even Shoshan, he holds (Z"L) that Hebrew came from proto-Canaanite / Akkadian, and he says אדון comes from Canaanite אדנ or Akkadian אדנ - strong, powerful.

Comment: I didn't look inside at Even Shoshan, but אדון is usually considered to have come from אד + the ending -ון (as in the Canaanite name אדורם, Solomon's tax officer), so I think points 2 and 3 aren't etymologically correct

Comment: @ba Interesting, E.SH says אד (steam, vapor, no other meaning found) comes from Akkadian "edu" for a flood. How is it connected to אדון?

Comment: I think R’ Hirsch agreed to point #2 but holds that אדון is indeed from אדן, as the master of something is the base upon which everything else is built - all according to his wishes. Something to that effect.

Comment: @DonielF Seems too distant, like in a master-and-slave relation I wouldn't call the master - a base.

Comment: @AlBerko Support is really a better translation of אדן. I hear your point, but it’s not unusual for R’ Hirsch to discuss such reasons when it’s clear (to him) that these words are of the same root. I tend to agree with that premise, as it’s not unusual for a ו to be added or removed in the middle of a root, but to take an א and tack it on the front of a word requires that it means “I will.” Thus, if אדון really came from the root דון it should mean “I will judge” rather than “master.” Then what needs to be clarified is where the connection comes from, but to me it seems obvious that it’s there

Comment: Not אֵד as in steam, but אָד, which doesn't exist in Hebrew, but apparently did in Canaanite languages, so may have been the source of אדון along with the -ון suffix; see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adon) or [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%9D) on this

Comment: @AlBerko Are there any rabbinical sources where it is discussed that the word אדן at Shemot 38:31 is the same word אדן when used in reference to Hashem?

Comment: @DonielF when you write, "Support is really a better translation of אדן", are you saying (and this is a neutral question): that the word אדן at Shemot 38:31 is the same word אדן when used in reference to Hashem, who is our אדן, our Support?

Comment: @ninamag Perfect way of putting it.